# Mounting a thumb drive encrypted o OS X yosemite on Debian

Tags: macos, debian, encryption, mount

I recently encrypted a thumb drive on mac OS X Yosemite, by right-clicking on it and choosing "encrypt volume". Now I want to mount it on Debian jessie (read only access is sufficient). However, I haven't found a way to do so.

The drive looks like this:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 7,4 GiB, 7927234560 bytes, 15482880 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B01C700F-FCE2-4CEF-B0C3-1525CC5EC52A

Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1        40   409639   409600  200M EFI System
/dev/sdc2    409640 15220695 14811056  7,1G Apple Core storage
/dev/sdc3  15220696 15482839   262144  128M Apple boot
```

Is it possible to decrypt/mount the drive on jessie?

As a bonus it would be really neat if I could do so, with software available from the Debian archive.

Comment: I don't think I know enough to answer. I deleted my answer.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer That's unfortunate, but still thanks for trying.